# LibGDX how to get button from clickListener

Tags: java, button, libgdx, imagebutton

To be honest I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I want to get `ImageButton` object from `ClickListener`, but something goes wrong.

```
 public void createButton() {
    button = new ImageButton(this.skin);
    buttonUnitsList.add(button);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
           selectedUnit = buttonUnitsList.indexOf(this.getButton());
        }
    });       
}
```

Comment: "Something"?  Do you get an error?  Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: No, i have no errors, but for all buttons selectedUnit value after click is always the same.

Comment: What is `getButton()`?  I'm guessing it returns `button`, which will always be the last button created.

Comment: Oh, it's funny and i didn't even noticed that - getButton() returns int, and it's set by argument of ClickListener() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `Actor` instance on which event was fired you need to use `getTarget()` Event's method. If you are sure that the listener will be used only with buttons you can upcast this from `Actor` to `Button`

```
selectedUnit = buttonUnitsList.indexOf((Button)event.getTarget());
```

Notice that if you will use the listener for another type of Actor you will get casting Exception

Comment: It worked for me. I can't cast Actor to ImageButton, but i get parent and it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: glad to help, If answer resolves your problem you can [accep it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

`event.getTarget()` can be dangerous to use if you have a hierarchy in the actor.

For example, imagine you have :

```
Group Actor <= ImageButton Actor 1 <= Label Actor 1
            <= ImageButton Actor 2 <= Label Actor 2
            <= ImageButton Actor 3 <= Label Actor 3
```

and you Create an eventListener on the Group Actor.

`event.getTarget()` will give you the actor where you click exactly

If you click on the "ImageButton Actor 2" for example, you could try `event.getTarget().getParent()` to get the Group Actor, but it won't work if you click on one of a Label Actor (the parent will be the corresponding ImageButton)

The best way to do, is to get the Actor which create the EventListener by `event.getListenerActor()`